# Indexing a database

Tags: sql, indexing

I want to index a db. But in most of the table foreign key constraints are not set.So before start indexing whether we have to set the foreign key for all tables? Or just index the table columns according to the queries.Please give your valuable suggestions.

Mahesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short Answer: Indexes do not rely on foreign keys or their constraints, foreign keys can enhanced by indexes though.. but indexes are often placed on columns that are NOT foreign keys.

Little detail: You should look at what you are searching for within your tables, and create indexes on those columns - but take that step seriously, indexing is a valuable process in database design, but can hurt you if done incorrectly.

Comment: So if we mark a column as foreign key whether it index automatically like primary key

Comment: You are asking about two different things, foreign key constraints are like relationship validations, and indexes are a way to 'chunk' data into buckets so that when you run queries your queries run against smaller tables depending on the cardinality of the given table. Creating a foreign key constraint will not create an index, it will just assure that the key that is provided in that column, is actually a value in the foreign table.

Answer (score 2):

Yes: Create Foreign Keys where the Domain requires them (i.e. all relationships to PK's).  Even without indexes the optimiser will take these into account.

You can start by defining indexes on all FK columns, but it would be better to capture a representative query workload to determine your most expensive queries, and then index accordingly.

Comment: Your second paragraph is correct, but your first is not so much - you can create indexes of columns that contain dates, and integers for instance that are not in fact foreign keys... Indexes are used to alleviate the stress of expensive queries, they have nothing to do with foreign key constraints..

Comment: @Rabbot: Yes, I'm aware of that. The first paragraph is also correct: In addition to being Domain constraints, the optimiser uses FK's to make decisions (as well as indexes)